# What is different between a function without start underscore and with an underscore in PHP?

Tags: php

I noticed that my senior wrote a few function names start with an underscore and some are normal. For example

```
funtion getData()
{
    return someData;
}

funtion _getData()
{
    return someData;
}
```

When I question that, He said _getData() function more secure to compare normal function. 
But I didn't understand. How it becomes more secure with an underscore. Is it true? if it is true. Can you explain more detailed example?

**Note**: I knew about __constructor(). It starts with double underscores.

Comment: *"But I didn't understand."* - Neither did he.  If your colleague can't explain *why* it's "more secure" then your colleague is relying on spells and incantations instead of knowledge.  Tread carefully when attempting to learn anything from this colleague.  (Hint: It isn't "more secure".  It has nothing to do with security.  Never has.)

Comment: For the code and the interpreter there isn't any difference between `function getData()` and `function _getData()`. Starting the name with an underscore is an old code convention since the old days of PHP 4 that didn't support `protected` or `private` members. It is obsolete and not useful nowadays.